# Play 2.0.4 / Ebean 2.7.3 - DB primary key sequencing

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I have got a problem with Play Framework 2.0.4.

I have models managed through the Ebean ORM. These models have numerical primary key IDs (int) with sequence auto generator. Underlying database is PostgreSQL.

The problem is, when I save a new object to database, ID is selected in range from 1 to 20 + last ID from the database. I found out from the Play source, that this is connected to  database batch size. If I change batch size to 1. Everything should be ok. I found a way on how to change desired value here https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaEbean. Anyway it seems that there is no ServerConfigStartup interface in my version of Ebean (2.7.3). Probably it is new feature in 2.7.5. The other way using ebean.properties is ignored in my Play version.

The question is.. Is there any way to change batch size in Play 2.0.4 .. or .. Is there any way to force Ebean/PostgreSQL to use ID sequencing with increment of 1 ?

Comment: Allright, I found a temporary solution. I patched the EbeanPlugin.java directly in 2.0.4 release, recompiled and voila it is working. I forced desired behavior by adding line config.setDatabaseSequenceBatchSize(1) to Ebean configuration. I know .. it is ugly, but functional. In current GIT version it is fixed in other way. Hopefuly it will become stable soon so I will be able to switch to original code.

Comment: I had similar problem as I encountered id collisions as the sequence rolled over e.g. 17,18,19,1,2,4... in an insert loop. In the end I switched to UUIDs.